# How can I rotate the layout logic from Apple's CircleLayout 90 degrees to the left?

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Apple released an example of a Circular Layout when it announced UICollectionViews last year. I am using it to get me going with a circular layout. The problem is that I would like to use 5 cells, and that just so happens to line up wonky:

[image]

I am not much of a math wiz, and am frankly having trouble understanding how the code below is making everything circular:

```
- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes*) layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)path {
          UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForCellWithIndexPath:path];
          attributes.size = CGSizeMake(ITEM_SIZEw, ITEM_SIZEh);
          attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x +_radius *
                                cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount),
                                _center.y + _radius *
                                sinf(2 * path.item * M_PI/ _cellCount));

          return attributes;
 }
```

So how can I adjust this math so that the circles layout rotated left 90 degrees? Or to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does the positioning:

```
attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x +_radius *
                    cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount),
                    _center.y + _radius *
                    sinf(2 * path.item * M_PI/ _cellCount));
```

The point on a circle around `(0,0)` at angle `α` (going upwards, starting at the rightmost point of the circle) has cordinates `(radius * cos(α), radius * sin(α))`.

So you can see from the code that the first item is placed at the right. Note that cosf does not take degrees but radian as its parameter.

To have the first item placed at the top, just add 90° (`=π/2`) to the angles. So the quoted code should be:

```
attributes.center = CGPointMake(_center.x +_radius *
                    cosf(2 * path.item * M_PI / _cellCount + M_PI / 2),
                    _center.y + _radius *
                    sinf(2 * path.item * M_PI/ _cellCount + M_PI / 2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Had to divide by .66666 in order to get it rotated the way I am looking for. Your answer got me going though. Thanks!

Comment: What happened when you used my code? It should definitely work.

Comment: it rotated it to the right, putting the top circle at the bottom. I was looking to get the top circle at the top.

Comment: ah, then the cos and sin functions used here are unusual – then you need to substract `π/2`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `_center.x + _radius * cosf(…)` to `_center.x - _radius * sinf(…)` and
`_center.y + _radius * sinf(…)` to `_center.y - _radius * cosf(…)`.

Relative to the center, your point on the circle for angle α is at `x=r*cos(α)` and `y=r*sin(α)`. This corresponds with the common coordinate system where angles are measured from the x axis in counter-clockwise direction. But for α=0 you want the top position, which  is `x=0, y=-r` assuming a standard computer coordinate system where the `y` axis points down If it points up, flip the sign. At α=0 you have `sin(α)=0, cos(α)=1`, so you want `x=±r*sin(α), y=-r*cos(α)`. Now as you increase α, the cos will decrease (which is what you want, to move down) and the sin will increase. So if you want to move counter-clockwise, then you want to *subtract* that sin, i.e. `x=-r*sin(α)`. Add the coordinates of the center, reuse the existing expression for α, and you are done.